# Why cant my code check if the number is odd or even?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why cant my code check if the number is odd or even?
The alert always says that the number is odd. 
The result is the same whether I have x in the function brackets or not.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  function check(x){
   if(x % 2 == 0){
    alert('even');
   } else{
    alert('odd');
   }
  }
  function store(x){
   function save(x){
    var x = document.getElementById('x');
    localStorage.setItem('x',x.value);
   }
   save(x);
   check(x);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form" onsubmit="store()">
  <label>x=</label>
  <input type="text" id="x">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because NaN !== 0. See here: `onsubmit="store()"`, no `x` passed.

Comment: 1. You need to pass in the value of X
     <form onsubmit="store(this.elements.x.value)">

2. function store() needs to return false to stop the submission process

3. as mentioned earlier, you might wnt to ensure the value being returned is a number.

Comment: i tried it and it still doesnt work

Comment: @bobtan What did you try? You've to pass the value of the input to `store` to get this work.

Comment: @Teemu i put the x in the brackets

Comment: You've to define it first, just like you do in `save`.

Comment: @Teemu how tho im new to this

Comment: Please read carefully the dup Cerbrus has linked, there you can find your answer.

Comment: @Teemu i've read it and defined var x in both functions but it still alerts odd